# Are there any descent symmetry tables for character tables of linear structures?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory

I know about tables containing information about descending in symmetry, i.e. from larger point  groups to their sub-groups.

We can see such tables in [this answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3454/53653), or in [this PDF](http://www3.uji.es/~planelle/APUNTS/TGS/taules_TG_oxford.pdf).

**My question is - does any similar table exist even for $C_{\infty v}$ and $D_{\infty h}$ point groups?**

Comment: On page 80 (Chapter 3) of 'Molecular Symmetry and Group Theory' by R. Carter, publ Wiley there are tables for the partial descent from $C_{\infty V} \to C_{2V}$ and $D_{\infty h} \to D_{2h}$ and more importantly with an explanation of how to derive them.

Comment: @porphyrin Thank you! Do you mean the [2009 edition](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Molecular_Symmetry_And_Group_Theory.html?id=4OpVcAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)?

Comment: my edition is 1998 but it should be in newer editions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here they are, finally I found them in some random presentation for a lecture:

$$\begin{array}{c|c} \hline
D_{\infty \mathrm h} & D_\mathrm{2h} \\ \hline
\mathrm{\Sigma_g^+} & \mathrm{A_g} \\
\mathrm{\Sigma_g^-} & \mathrm{B_{1g}} \\
\mathrm{\Pi_g} & \mathrm{B_{2g} + B_{3g}} \\
\mathrm{\Delta_g} & \mathrm{A_{g} + B_{1g}} \\
\mathrm{\Sigma_u^+} & \mathrm{B_{1u}} \\
\mathrm{\Sigma_u^-} & \mathrm{A_u} \\
\mathrm{\Pi_u} & \mathrm{B_{2u} + B_{3u}} \\
\mathrm{\Delta_u} & \mathrm{A_{u} + B_{1u}} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|c} \hline
C_{\infty \mathrm v} & C_\mathrm{2v} \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1 = \Sigma^+} & \mathrm{A_1} \\
\mathrm{A_2 = \Sigma^-} & \mathrm{A_2} \\
\mathrm{E_1 = \Pi} & \mathrm{B_1 + B_2}\\
\mathrm{E_2 = \Delta} & \mathrm{A_1 + A_2} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$